# Print whole line which starts from given letter

Tags: c, loops, file, c-strings

I'm trying to print lines which starts from given letter to second file but it prints only 1 line and then stops, even if there are more lines which starts with given letter. How to fix it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("story.txt","r");
    char usr;
    printf("enter letter: ");
    scanf(" %c",&usr);

    FILE* f2=fopen("letter.txt","a+");

    char buffer[255];
       while(fscanf(f, "%[^\n]s", buffer)==1)
        if (*buffer == usr)
          fprintf(f2, "%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `s` after `%[^\n]`? Did someone teach you that `[^\n]` is a prefix modifier of `%s`?

Comment: @Barmar nobody taught me that, I'm new to C, I didn't know that it's bad.

Comment: If you're new to C, where did you learn it? It shouldn't be in any tutorial.

Comment: It was my own mistake to write like this.

Comment: It's a very common beginner mistake, I always wonder where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time through the loop, `fscanf(f, "%[^\n]s", buffer)` fails to scan anything because the previous call left the `\n` character in the buffer. This can't get past that.

Use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()` to read a whole line.

```
    char buffer[255];
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f))
        if (buffer[0] == usr)
            fprintf(f2, "%s", buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `fscanf` to read line of text.

```
//fi - input file
//fo - output file
int copyLines(FILE *fi, FILE *fo, char c)
{
    char line[256];
    if(fi && fo)
    {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fi))
        {
            if(*line = c)
                if(fputs(line, fo) == EOF) return EOF;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters the format string in the call of `fscanf` is incorrect

```
while(fscanf(f, "%[^\n]s", buffer)==1)
                      ^^^
```

At least you should remove the letter `s`.

Another problem is that after such a call of `fscanf` the new line character `'\n'` is not read. So the next call of `fscanf` reads an empty string.

It is better to use another C function `fgtes`. But you need to use it with a caution.

In general a string stored in the input file can be greater than the size of the array `buffer`.

That means that you need to read some strings in the input file using more than one call of `fgets`. Otherwise the output file will be formed incorrectly.

The loop can look the following way

```
int success = 1;

do
{
    success = fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), f ) != NULL;
    if ( success )
    {
        int target = *buffer == usr;

        if ( target ) fprintf( f2, "%s", buffer );
        while ( success && !strchr( buffer, '\n' ) )
        { 
            success = fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), f ) != NULL;
            if ( success && target ) fprintf( f2, "%s", buffer );
        }
    }
}  while ( success );
```